# Getting error when run the application in Jboss Cloud server 6.4.8

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

Presently we are migrating our application from Jboss 6.0 to Cloud Jboss Server 6.4.8. After Deployment in new cloud server, When I hit the application URL .. Getting the below error :

```
2017-05-25 07:08:42,550 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/eWeb].[jsp]]  JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "class" attribute is not allowed on the div element!
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.error(StylesheetHandler.java:907) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.error(StylesheetHandler.java:950) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTElementProcessor.setPropertiesFromAttributes(XSLTElementProcessor.java:348) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTElementProcessor.setPropertiesFromAttributes(XSLTElementProcessor.java:268) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.ProcessorLRE.startElement(ProcessorLRE.java:283) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.startElement(StylesheetHandler.java:626) [xalan-2.7.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:496)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
```

Comment: Totally unreadable. Don't copy the whole log, did you noticed that it repeats 3 times?

Comment: Yes Alex , error repeats 3 times